# How to retrieve a youtube video keywords with php

Tags: php, youtube, keyword

I'm trying to get videos keywords using video id (or url).
I've googled it and found ways to get videos info (title, length,..etc) but didn't find a way to get keywords.
So..how to retrieve a youtube video keywords with php

code:

```
    $entry = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?v=2');
    $keywords = (string) $entry->children('media', TRUE)->group->keywords;

    $keywords_array = explode(", ", $keywords);
    print_r($keywords_array);
```

Comment: What's your expected and actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy you will get something like:

```
    Array
    (
```

because you must be the uploader of the video - you must provide a key first..
simply you can't extract it from videos you don't own!!

Answer (score 1):

You need the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) for that.

you'll be looking for:

```
snippet.tags[]
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties

Get you credentials on [Google APIs Console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties)

Example query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=Lg7vPFnTuMg&order=date&key=YOURKEY
```